# Should we or should we not support questions on Unity 8?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

You are all aware Unity 8 is not ready yet, so, should questions about it be off topic?

I vote off topic, it is in no way ready yet, perhaps [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix) would take it?

Example question: [Snap Launching on Unity 7 But Not Unity 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845465/snap-launching-on-unity-7-but-not-unity-8)

Comment: To those voting - vote up or down on the answers so we get a consensus, not on the question, please.

Comment: Was it incorrect or improper for me to tell OP that Unity 8 wasn't stable? (just a quick question, I'm fairly sure OP in that question is on proprietary nVidia drivers which don't support Mir correctly yet).

Comment: @PatrickNegus No, of course not, it is always good to advise someone that something may simply not work, IMO you handled it just right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a program included in a supported version, and the default environment on tablets/phones.

Unless the question is about a bug, or dependant on some unmade feature we should be able to handle many of these questions. Like running various xapps on the desktop, tweaks or installing silos. This stuff should certainly be on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I guess +11/-7 is a good consensus, I will accept this to show the community wishes to support Unity 8.

Answer (score -7):

Unity 8 is in development. So it is off-topic.